# #each for Meteor.js template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

I am trying to make it so users only see questions they haven't answered already. I have set it up so when user answers a question it updates their account with `questionsAnswered` and updates the questions `usersTrue` and `usersFalse` arrays. I am using the each template function to loop through my question collection to show all active questions.

I have tried to add some add extra parameter to the `.find({active: true})` but that doesn't work.

I have a helper for my each loop. I have tried adding a if else that doesn't work.

I would prefer to loop through the user's `questionsAnswered` array to see if they have already answered the question.

Template

```
<template name="questionCard">
{{#each questions}}
        <div id="{{_id}}" class="card">
            {{ que}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="no option" href="#">No</a>
            <a class="yes option" href="#">Yes</a>
        </div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Javascript (helper) code:

```
Template.questionCard.helpers({
'questions': function(){
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    return QuestionList.find({active: true});
}
});
```

I would like for the card to disappear after they answer, but that problem should solve itself if the loop is fixed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What result are you getting in the html template?FYI: you are returning a cursor in the helper, try fetching the as an array `QuestionList.find({acitve:true}).fetch()`

Comment: @Rajanand02 This is actually correct, the Meteor rendering engine works better with cursors than with arrays as those returned with `fetch`.

Comment: is there any subscription on `QuestionList` collection?

Comment: Yes there is a subscription. How can I use fetch for this? I thought it was for javascript console only.

Comment: Please post your publications and subscriptions.

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of userstrue and usersfalse array and also about active property

Comment: The userTrue and userFalse are to log how users voted. My other problem I have is I want to loop through those users and update their score based on the answer. I was going to post another stackoverflow question once I figure this part out.

Comment: Publications `Meteor.publish('activeQuestions', function(){
 var currentUserId = this.userId
 return QuestionList.find({ });
});
Meteor.publish('userAnswer', function(){
 var currentUserId = this.userId
 return UserList.find({_id: currentUserId});
});`

Subscriptions `Meteor.subscribe('activeQuestions');
Meteor.subscribe('userAnswer');
` 

Im sure I am not using publish and subscribe to their full power.

Comment: Your **currentUser** variable declaration isn't doing anything in the code from your question.

Comment: Would you please update your question to show all relevant code instead adding it to a comment? It would be helpful to see it along with the file names that contain the code, as Meteor requires certain code to be on the client and other code to be on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting some help from someone at crater.io. I was trying to add information to the javascript side to check to see if userId was not in the array. I was introduced to the $nin operator so my code ended up looking like this.

Thanks for your responses!

```
Template.questionCard.helpers({
'questions': function(){
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    return QuestionList.find({active: true, usersTrue: {$nin: [currentUser]}, 
    usersFalse: {$nin: [currentUser]}});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do the following:

**1. Create a server side file, such as server/publications.js, to hold the publish declaration**

**2. Define it inside that file:**

```
Meteor.publish("questionList", function() {
  return QuestionList.find({});
});
```